# Cucumber "puts" in After hook not outputting anything

Tags: ruby, cucumber

In Cucumber, in my `env.rb` file, I have a before & after hook set up (well, a few of them, some linked to specific tags) but have found the after hooks don't output anything when I put a `puts` in them.

For example, this works:

```
Before do
  puts "before the scenario"
end
```

but this doesn't:

```
After do
  puts "after the scenario"
end
```

It seems that the after hooks do get run (as there's a particular line I'm having a problem with in the after hook & in trying to debug that, I've found this problem) but they're just not outputting anything.

All my searching has proved fruitless, can't find anyone else with similar problems. Can anyone tell if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: If you're trying to test that the hooks get run at all, doing a `raise` might be more effective (and certainly easier to notice) than a `puts`.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in the question, I already know the hooks are being run.  I'm just curious as to why "puts" doesn't output anything in an After hook.  Is it the same for you (and others)?  or just me?

Comment: Well it doesn't seem as if you're doing anything wrong. If you're using a custom formatter you might want to try switching back to the default, as a custom one might suppress more output.

Comment: Try changing it to `STDERR.puts "after the scenario"`—maybe cucumber is doing something strange with `STDOUT`?

Comment: Yes -- Len, that is it.  That worked.  Strange, though.  I'm using "--format pretty" in the profile, is that what you mean, Andrew?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Cucumber overrides the `puts` message in the `RbWorld` class so that anything written with `puts` gets properly broadcasted to all formatters.  In the case of the `pretty` formatter, these go into a `delayed_messages` collection, until it calls `print_messages`, which it appears to do after each step name has been printed, presumably so that messages appear to be nested under the step in which they were generated.

For some reason there is no final call to `print_messages` in the pretty formatter, I'm not sure if it's an omission or deliberate since it would look less 'pretty' to have spurious messages in the output.

Interestingly if you add a second scenario, you'll see 'after the scenario' printed as the first message when the second scenario gets run, that's the `delayed_messages` collection in action.

In summary, you're doing nothing wrong, it's just how Cucumber hijacks the `puts` method.  If you're not too bothered about these messages being nicely formatted, then you can just replace `puts` with `STDOUT.puts` to bypass Cucumber's formatting.

Comment: Interestingly, with`puts` the line `"before the scenario"` would appear in the output _after_ the first step, which makes you think the `Before` hook is run after the first step instead of before any of the scenario steps.
Using `STDOUT.puts` fixes that.

Answer (score 7):

```
 Before do
     p "Go!"
     puts "Go!"
 end

 After do
     p "Stop!"
     puts "Stop!"
     $stdout.puts "Stop!"
 end
```

output of this snippet may help to understand why 'puts' not working in After hook.

Comment: Ah - ok, so I changed it slightly, and ran this instead:  
`Before do
p "in before p"
puts "in before puts"
end
After do
p "in before p"
puts "in before puts"
end`
and I can see the "p"'s are being printed, but only the "before puts" is appearing, and it's appearing just after first step is executed.

Comment: sorry, formatting's a bit whack.  So that does help a bit -- I can use "p" instead of "puts", didn't think of that, but still curious as to why "puts" in an After hook doesn't work.

Comment: The $stdout is a global variable which holds the standard output stream.